# Understanding error in For loop statement Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

The code is:

```
def trans(old):
    length = len(old)
    new = []
    new = old
    for i in range(0,length):
        print(old[length-i-1])
    for i in range(0,length):
        new[i] = old[length-i-1]
        print("new:",new[i],"  [i]:",i,"  old:",old[length-i-1]," length-
        i-1:",length-i-1)
    ihavenoideawhatimdoing = " ".join(new)
    return new
```

Instruction:
 1. def trans(old): Input sentence in `(old)`
 2. length(len): Take number of elements in the sentence
 3. `new = []` and `new = old` is to make a container with the same size for the new word
 4. First `for` loop = I wanted to see the words in the original sentence backwards
 5. My problem is in the second `for` loop. See the output
 6. What comes next is related to the problem I'm solving but not to the problem I'm having

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNbH4.jpg)

Input sentence: "please help me solve this"

I didn't any label for the next batch of words but it's supposed to be:
old(length-0-1) -> old(5-0-1) -> old(4): this
old(3): solve
old(2): me
old(1):help
old(0): please

Now, what's iffy is in the next `for` statement at length-i-1 = 1 where instead of being "help", it's "solve."

Both codes are familiar so I'm stuck at what else could be wrong.

Comment: `new = old` makes the name `new` refer to the same object as `old`. So if you change the contents of one, the other is also changed.

Comment: It doesn't just assign the contents for `old` into `new`? So *any* change into `new` is applied to `old`?

edit: just saw the duplicate question. Thanks for helping~

Comment: @Monxstar: `=` never copies anything, it just makes the name on the left refer to the value on the right. As they both refer to the same thing, a change is visible using both (but it's still only one object being changed). `new = list(old)` as AChampion says does make a new list with the contents of `old`.

Comment: @AChampion: I have doubts that it is a string, as then he would have got an exception at the `new[i] = `line.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich good point, assumed sentence = `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def trans(old):

    new = old.split(" ")
    new_str = ""
    for i in reversed(new):
        new_str = new_str + " " + i
    print new_str
```